# why pulumi kubernetes provider is changing the service and deployment name?

Tags: kubernetes, pulumi

I tried to convert the below working kubernetes manifest from

```yaml
##namespace
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: poc

##postgress
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: db
  name: db
  namespace: poc
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: db
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: db
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: postgres
        name: postgres
        env:
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          value: postgres
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: postgres
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
          name: postgres
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: db
  name: db
  namespace: poc
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: "db-service"
    port: 5432
    targetPort: 5432
  selector:
    app: db

##adminer
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ui
  name: ui
  namespace: poc
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ui
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ui
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: adminer
        name: adminer
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: ui
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ui
  name: ui
  namespace: poc
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: "ui-service"
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: ui
```

to

```js
import * as k8s from "@pulumi/kubernetes";
import * as kx from "@pulumi/kubernetesx";

//db
const dbLabels = { app: "db" };
const dbDeployment = new k8s.apps.v1.Deployment("db", {
    spec: {
        selector: { matchLabels: dbLabels },
        replicas: 1,
        template: {
            metadata: { labels: dbLabels },
            spec: { 
                containers: [
                    { 
                        name: "postgres", 
                        image: "postgres",
                        env: [{ name: "POSTGRES_USER", value: "postgres"},{ name: "POSTGRES_PASSWORD", value: "postgres"}],
                        ports: [{containerPort: 5432}]
                    }
                ] 
            }
        }
    }
});

const dbService = new k8s.core.v1.Service("db", {
    metadata: { labels: dbDeployment.spec.template.metadata.labels },
    spec: {
        selector: dbLabels,
        type: "ClusterIP",
        ports: [{ port: 5432, targetPort: 5432, protocol: "TCP" }],
    }
});

//adminer
const uiLabels = { app: "ui" };
const uiDeployment = new k8s.apps.v1.Deployment("ui", {
    spec: {
        selector: { matchLabels: uiLabels },
        replicas: 1,
        template: {
            metadata: { labels: uiLabels },
            spec: { 
                containers: [
                    { 
                        name: "adminer", 
                        image: "adminer",
                        ports: [{containerPort: 8080}],
                    }
                ] 
            }
        }
    }
});

const uiService = new k8s.core.v1.Service("ui", {
    metadata: { labels: uiDeployment.spec.template.metadata.labels },
    spec: {
        selector: uiLabels,
        type: "NodePort",
        ports: [{ port: 8080, targetPort: 8080, protocol: "TCP" }]
    }
});
```

With this `pulumi up -y` is SUCCESS without error but the application is not fully UP and RUNNING. Because the `adminer` image is trying to use Postgres database hostname as `db`, But looks like pulumi is changing the service name like below:

[image]

My question here is, How to make this workable?
Is there a way in pulumi to strict with the naming?

Note- I know we can easily pass the hostname as an env variable to the `adminer` image but I am wondering if there is anything that can allow us to not change the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulumi automatically adds random strings to your resources to help with replacing resource. You can find more information about this in the [FAQ](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/troubleshooting/faq/#why-do-resource-names-have-random-hex-character-suffixes)

If you'd like to disable this, you can override it using the `metadata`, like so:

```ts
import * as k8s from "@pulumi/kubernetes";
import * as kx from "@pulumi/kubernetesx";

//db
const dbLabels = { app: "db" };
const dbDeployment = new k8s.apps.v1.Deployment("db", {
    spec: {
        selector: { matchLabels: dbLabels },
        replicas: 1,
        template: {
            metadata: { labels: dbLabels },
            spec: { 
                containers: [
                    { 
                        name: "postgres", 
                        image: "postgres",
                        env: [{ name: "POSTGRES_USER", value: "postgres"},{ name: "POSTGRES_PASSWORD", value: "postgres"}],
                        ports: [{containerPort: 5432}]
                    }
                ] 
            }
        }
    }
});
    
const dbService = new k8s.core.v1.Service("db", {
    metadata: { 
        name: "db", // explicitly set a name on the service
        labels: dbDeployment.spec.template.metadata.labels 
    },
    spec: {
        selector: dbLabels,
        type: "ClusterIP",
        ports: [{ port: 5432, targetPort: 5432, protocol: "TCP" }],
    }
});
```

With that said, it's not always best practice to hardcode names like this, you should, if possible, reference outputs from your resources and pass them to new resources.